# pylint and astroid AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'col_offset'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, pylint, pylintrc, astroid

It fails using [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) version `2.9.0` and `2.9.3`. With version [2.8.3](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/2.8.3/) it still works though.

See [GitHub-issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4671) under the provided link.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/inference_tip.py", line 19, in _inference_tip_cached
    return iter(_cache[func, node])
KeyError: (<function register_builtin_transform.<locals>._transform_wrapper at 0x7f310b222700>, <Call l.166 at 0x7f3102ebf970>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/bin/pylint", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 24, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/run.py", line 384, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 973, in check
    self._check_files(
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1007, in _check_files
    self._check_file(get_ast, check_astroid_module, name, filepath, modname)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1033, in _check_file
    check_astroid_module(ast_node)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1170, in check_astroid_module
    retval = self._check_astroid_module(
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1215, in _check_astroid_module
    walker.walk(ast_node)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/utils/ast_walker.py", line 77, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/utils/ast_walker.py", line 77, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/utils/ast_walker.py", line 74, in walk
    callback(astroid)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py", line 1071, in visit_assign
    self._check_assignment_from_function_call(node)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py", line 1081, in _check_assignment_from_function_call
    function_node = safe_infer(node.value.func)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/checkers/utils.py", line 1177, in safe_infer
    value = next(infer_gen)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/node_classes.py", line 353, in infer
    yield from self._infer(context, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 136, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 100, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/inference.py", line 299, in infer_attribute
    for owner in self.expr.infer(context):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/node_classes.py", line 367, in infer
    for i, result in enumerate(generator):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 136, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 100, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/bases.py", line 144, in _infer_stmts
    for inferred in stmt.infer(context=context):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/node_classes.py", line 367, in infer
    for i, result in enumerate(generator):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 136, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 100, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/bases.py", line 144, in _infer_stmts
    for inferred in stmt.infer(context=context):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/node_classes.py", line 343, in infer
    results = tuple(self._explicit_inference(self, context, **kwargs))
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/inference_tip.py", line 21, in _inference_tip_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_builtin_inference.py", line 203, in _transform_wrapper
    if result.col_offset is None:
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'col_offset'
```

The `requirements.txt` - file of this testing environment contains:

```
astroid
src/packages/project/requirements.txt
pycodestyle
pylint
pylint_junit
pytest
pytest-cov
yapf
```

with `src/packages/project/requirements.txt` containing:

```
awswrangler==2.8.0
babel==2.9.1
boto3==1.17.77
botocore==1.20.77
category-encoders==2.2.2
joblib==1.0.1
markdown==3.3.4
matplotlib==3.3.4
openpyxl==3.0.7
pandas==1.1.5
pyarrow==4.0.0
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
scikit-learn==0.24.2
simple_salesforce==1.0.0
```

**EDIT on different attempts producing the same error:**

1. Installing `pylint=2.9.3`
2. Installing `astroid` and `pylint` (latest versions, no version specification)
3. Installing `astroid` and `pylint` and upgrade `astroid` to latest version during build-process (in AWS test-buildspec.yml) via `pip install --upgrade astroid` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28303917/12298276))

Comment: Can you post which versions you're using? `pip list`

Comment: It failed for pylint version `2.9.0`.

Comment: Have you tried updating to latest patch of that pylint release, at this time 2.9.3. `pip install --upgrade pylint==2.9.3` and seeing if the issue is resolved?

Comment: I've just updated the OP with all python-packages involved in this testing environment, as well listing some attempts which did not work out to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the work of @Pierre.Sassoulas this issue has been resolved (see [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4671)).

After having proven that the following combination of `pylint` - and `astroid` - versions worked well together without producing the OP-error, new commits have been made to the [GitHub-project](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) to fix the problem:

```
pip install pylint==2.9.3
pip install git+git://github.com/PyCQA/astroid.git@c37b6fd47b62486fd6cbe77b913b568b809f1a6d#egg=astroid
```

From here going forward, the issue should not occur again installing the latest version of pylint combined with astroid. Yet, if the issue returns, I'll let you know here.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you found a bug/crash in pylint `2.9`, you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/new/choose). You can downgrade to 2.8.3 while it's being fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'd already downgraded it so long.
Maybe with the current version of `2.9.3` the bug has been fixed already. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I've tried it out with the new versions, but only the old one `2.8.3` seems to be working (see OP).